# How to include template variables in ngClass condition with string with angular2/4/5?

Tags: angular

How do I concatenate a string with a template variable with Angular 2/4/5 in an ngClass condition? The following is my template with some pseudocode of what I am trying to do, but am getting interpolation errors:

I have the following template:

```
<div *ngFor="item of listofitems">
   <span [ngClass]="{'turnedon': 'localvariable == 'SELECTOR_{{item.name}}'}">item.name</span>
</div>
```

The part I am struggling with is:

```
'SELECTOR_{{item.name}}
```

That is giving me errors. How can I make it so that I can put the item.name in there?

Or is this not possible and I need to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be

```
<div *ngFor="item of listofitems">
   <span [ngClass]="{'turnedon': localvariable == 'SELECTOR_' + item.name}">{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```